# KeyError('pandas._libs.interval') when opening a dataframe in Spyder

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, keyerror

When I try to click on data frames in the Variable Explorer in Spyder, I get the following error:[image: Spyder Error]

This happens with all data frames (I tried making my own).

As a side note, functions like `numpy.sum` and `.describe()` don't output anything, but I'm unsure if this is related to the KeyError.

Thank you!

Comment: Besides the dialog in the screenshot, you get any error stack trace somewhere? What output do you get in Spyder when you enter `import pandas; print(pandas.__file__)` and `import pandas._libs.interval; print(pandas._libs.interval.__file__)` in the interactive console?

Answer (score 0):

Add pandas to the packages option in `setup.py` module.

Here is the code snippet for `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['automating_finances0.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'packages': ['pandas']} 

setup(
  app=APP,
  data_files=DATA_FILES,
  options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
  setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

If this not works please try reinstalling pandas from pip as

`pip uninstall pandas`

`pip install pandas`

Comment: How do I access setup.py?

Comment: `setup.py` is a python file, the presence of which is an indication that the module/package you are about to install has likely been packaged and distributed with Distutils, which is the standard for distributing Python Modules.

Comment: follow this link https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html